# Hosting multiple websites on Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have a working website running on an Express server on a VPS on port 80. Now I want another website running on that same VPS with Express, but I'm not sure how I can make this happen. Is there a possibility that I can make this happen without having to copy all files to create a new website on a different port?

This is my www file in Express:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

var app = require('../app');
var debug = require('debug')('app:server');
var http = require('http');

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '80');
app.set('port', port);

var server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by another website? `domain.com/website1/mypage` and `domain.com/website2/mypage` or `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`?

Comment: I mean more like domain1.com and domain2.com

Comment: This is usually done by a lower level process like Nginx. You may have several Express apps running on different ports (say, 3000,4000 and 5000), and Nginx will redirect/map domains to these ports (for instance, domain1.com -> port 3000, domain2.com -> port 4000)

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-debian-8

Comment: Doesn't sound like a good idea to me....

Comment: What doesn't sound like a good idea?

Comment: Thank you Jeremy Thille. I've used Nginx for this and works like a charm :)